# how to prevent user to select location on the sea or ocean Flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps

it is so confusing but how to prevent the user to select a location on the sea or ocean in flutter google maps?
i am using `cameraTargetBounds` to restrict the user to newzealand country (for example) only but how to prevent him to pick a location inside the sea?

```
   cameraTargetBounds: new CameraTargetBounds(
                      new LatLngBounds(
                        northeast:  const LatLng(-175.81, -34.36),
                        southwest:  const LatLng(166.28, -47.35),
                      ),
```